# LINQ: Convert object[] into int?[]

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method, which one of its arguments is an array of objects, for example object[] data.
So I would like using LINQ to convert it into an array of int?, how to achieve this.
I need to skip only the first element in the array of objects.

For example, something like this (it is not compiling):

```
int?[] newData = data.Skip(1).Take(data.Length-1).ToArray<int?>();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you need `Take(data.Length - 1)`

```
int?[] newData = data.Skip(1).Take(data.Length - 1).Cast<int?>().ToArray();
```

It seems

```
int?[] newData = data.Skip(1).Cast<int?>().ToArray();
```

is enough (*all elements expect the first one*).

Comment: Also, if you only need read access to the output: consider leaving it as an `IEnumerable<int?>` instead of performing the `ToArray()`.

Comment: If the extracted items are, for example, simply being used in a **foreach** like this `foreach (var item in data.Skip(1).Cast<int?>()) { /* do something with each item */ }` then creating an array object is wasteful. The `IEnumerable<int?>` is quite adequate for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of two methods:

```
Cast<int?>
OfType<int?>
```

Cast will fail if one of elements will not be int?. OfType returns IEnumerable that will contains only elements of type int? from previous array.

So if your array contains elements of type int? excluding first element, you can use

```
int? [] newData = data.OfType<int?>().ToArray();
```